# Как заменить ссылку на картинку c помощью js

Tags: javascript

Ребята, столкнулся с проблемой. Никак не могу поменять ссылку на картинку. Задача наверняка несложная. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Кусок кода страницы:

```
<div class="t706__product-del">
   <img src="https://something.com/something.svg">
</div>
```

Это мой код, которым я пытаюсь изменить ссылку на картинку. Ничего не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var newcard = document.querySelector('.t706__product-del')
    newcard.setAttribute("src","/2.svg");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.t706__product-del` это div, вы пытаетесь добавить атрибут src тегу div, в этом проблема

```js
const newcard = document.querySelector('.t706__product-del img');
newcard.setAttribute('src', 'https://picsum.photos/100');
```

```html
<div class="t706__product-del">
   <img src="https://something.com/something.svg">
</div>
```

Если элемент появляется в DOM-дереве не сразу:

```js
function loop() {
  const newcard = document.querySelector('.t706__product-del img');
  if (newcard !== null) { // если элемент найден
    newcard.setAttribute('src', 'https://picsum.photos/100');
    return true;
  } else { // иначе он не найден
    return false;
  }
}

const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const resultLoop = loop();
  if (resultLoop === true) { // если элемент найден
    clearInterval(timer); // остановить setInterval
  }
}, 300);
```

```html
<div class="t706__product-del">
   <img src="https://something.com/something.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Но это не помогло, всё равно ссылка не поменялась, к сожалению. Я не против совершенно другого решения. Главное чтобы работало :)

Comment: @Павел на stackoverflow работает, нажмите выполнить код, посмотрите

Comment: Да, спасибо, действительно тут работает! Но у меня всё равно проблема не решилась. Такое ощущение, что в моём полном коде js не находит этот класс. Я ведь вам привел только часть кода. Данный класс '.t706__product-del img' является ребенком от множества других предков. Вы можете предположить в чём может быть дело?

Comment: @Павел возможно, вам нужно подождать, пока DOM дерево загрузится, или внутри этого класса есть несколько img

Comment: В данном скрипте я жду пока DOM дерево загрузится и внутри этого класса есть только одна img. В ссылке картинка с более полным кодом. https://yadi.sk/i/KNAx-o3r0esh5Q Если у вас будет время, поглядите, пожалуйста. Может быть вы поймете в чём дело. Буду вам очень признателен!

Comment: @Павел если этот элемент появляется от какого-то скрипта, надо подождать, пока он загрузится, а потом искать. Например, setInterval будет работать до тех пор, пока querySelector не получит элемент. Завтра напишу пример

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Всё получилось. Без вас я бы не справился, очень вам благодарен!!!

Comment: @Павел если вам мой ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой(находится ниже числа с кол-вом голосов)

Comment: Отметил:) Ещё раз большое вам спасибо!